# regarding custom report builder for .net

Tags: c#

basically i always develop report for our end user with crystal report or SSRS but now our client need that they will design report like choose report fields and they will position etc. i know this type of reporting is not possible by crystal report or SSRS where user will design and see the report. so please anyone give me the idea to develop this type of report for c# win application. is there already anything available like free report builder which i can use in my project and give the facility to my client that client will drag drop report filed on a surface like crystal report and view the report. please discuss this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [StimulReports](http://www.stimulsoft.com/ReportsUltimate.aspx) very successfully. They offer WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, Flash controls for embedding them into your application, as well as standalone report designers for WinForms and WPF. The redistribution is royalty-free. 
The nifty trick is to purchase the license from the Russian localized version of their web site, the prices are several times lower then when you buy from English localized version of their site. I'm not sure why this is so.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything free, used DevExpress XtraReports and it's fantastic, the royalty free end user report designer has ribbon user interface, can be distributed and does exactly all you asked, it's worth every single penny! if you want to compare products there are also other suites like ActiveReports or something from Telerik or Infragistic I believe, I have experience only with XtraReports and Crystal Reports and when moved from Crystal to XtraReports my productivity increased consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good reporting tool.

http://www.freereporting.com/